# Can OGR SQL dialect be used with GeoPackage?

Tags: python, sql, ogr, geopackage

I'm using GDAL (3.3.1) Python (3.8.11) bindings to process vector layers and am trying to use OGR SQL dialect to filter the layer, like this:

```
    sql = f"SELECT * from {out_lyr.GetName()} WHERE OGR_GEOM_AREA < {area_threshold}"
    out_lyr_selection = out_ds.ExecuteSQL(sql)
```

This works fine on FileGDB and Shapefile, when I try to use it on GeoPackage it gives the following error.

```
RuntimeError: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT * from merged WHERE OGR_GEOM_AREA < 20.0):
  no such column: OGR_GEOM_AREA
```

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/372398/48071) post suggests I should use "indirect_sqlite" dialect, so I checked the [OGR doc](https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html#spatialite-sql-functions) page. It suggested this would work:

```
    sql = f"SELECT * from {out_lyr.GetName()} WHERE ST_Area(GEOMETRY) < {area_threshold}"
    out_lyr_selection = out_ds.ExecuteSQL(sql, dialect="indirect_sqlite")
```

However, this time the error was:

```
RuntimeError: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT * from merged WHERE ST_Area(GEOMETRY) < 20.0):
  no such column: GEOMETRY
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible to use OGR SQL dialect to filter by area with GeoPackage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OGR SQL use `dialect="OGRSQL"`. It is the default SQL dialect but only when the datasource has no support for a native SQL dialect. Therefore if you read PostGIS, SpatiaLite, GeoPackage, Oracle etc. you must explicitly select the ORG SQL dialect.

When using indirect_sqlite dialect pay attention to error message `no such column: GEOMETRY`. Check the real name of the geometry column with ogrinfo. It can be whatever but quite often you will see

`Geometry Column = geom`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It was the dialect name I was missing - was trying "OGR SQL". If the correct name is written in the doc somewhere, I haven't found it. Also I didn't know about the geometry column name in `ogrinfo` - that's very handy.

Comment: Geometry name is reported if format allows to select it so it applies to database formats and XML/GML. The keywords of dialects are not really well enough documented in the documentation about SQL. Consider to help be pressing the "Edit on GitHub" button in https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html#ogr-sql-dialect and https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html. Adding the right keywords to use, emphasized as in the ogr2ogr documentation https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-dialect would help other users in the future.